Can multiple custom biomes share the same generation features?
I'm working on a custom dimension datapack, and the dimension is just two biomes. Whenever I try to generate terrain in that dimension, the game crashes, referencing a "feature order cycle" error. This means that generation features are called more than once. Here's where the problem lies: Of course they're called more than once. I have overlapping generation features in different custom biomes, and vanilla biomes do this too.
This error occurred previously in development, but it occurred when the same feature was called twice in a single biome. I've triple-checked that there are no duplicate features in either biome, and the terrain generates fine when all of the features are removed from one biome.
Could this be what's causing my crash, or is it something else? Can multiple custom biomes share the same generation features?
